# Write a function named spelling_corrector.

Tags: python, regex, string

Function should check each word in the input string against all the words in the correct_spells list and return a string such that:

- If a word in the original sentence matches exactly with a word in the
  correct_spells then the word is not modified and it should be
  directly copied to the output string.
- If a word in the sentence can match a word in the correct_spells list
  by replacing, inserting, or deleting a single character, then that
  word should be replaced by the correct word in the correct_spelled
  list.
- If neither of the two previous conditions is true, then the word in
  the original string should not be modified and should be directly
  copied to the output string.

Notes:

- Do not spell check one or two letter words (copy them directly to the
  output string).
- In case of a tie use the first word from the correct_spelled list.
- Ignore capitalization, i.e. consider capital letters to be the same
  as lower case letters.
- All characters in the output string should all be in lower case
  letters.
- Assume that the input string only includes alphabetic characters and
  spaces. (a-z and A-Z)
- Remove extra spaces between the words.
- Remove spaces at the start and end of the output string.

Examples:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMkKE.png)

Notice:

- In the first example 'thes' is not replaced with anything.
- In the first example both 'case' and 'car' could replace the 'cas' in the original sentence, but 'case' is selected because it was encountered first.

This is the code that I've tried but hasn't been very useful:

```
def spelling_corrector(input_string,input_list):
new_string = input_string.lower().split()
count = 0
for x in new_string:
    for y in input_list:
        for i in y:
            if i not in x:
                count += 1
    if count == 1:
        print(y)
    if len(x) == len(y) or x not in input_list:
        print(x)

spelling_corrector("Thes is the Firs cas", ['that','first','case','car'])`
```

Comment: For the second rule, [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def replace_1(bad:str, good:str) -> bool:
    """Return True if bad can be converted to good by replacing 1 letter.
    """
    if len(bad) != len(good):
        return False

    changes = 0
    for i,ch in enumerate(bad):
        if ch != good[i]:
            return bad[i+1:] == good[i+1:]

    return False

def insert_1(bad:str, good:str) -> bool:
    """Return True if bad can be converted to good by inserting 1 letter.
    """
    if len(bad) != len(good) - 1:
        return False

    for i,ch in enumerate(bad):
        if ch != good[i]:
            return bad[i:] == good[i+1:]

    # At this point, all of bad matches first part of good. So it's an
    # append of the last character.
    return True

def delete_1(bad:str, good:str) -> bool:
    """Return True if bad can be converted to good by deleting 1 letter.
    """
    if len(bad) != len(good) + 1:
        return False
    return insert_1(good, bad)


def correction(word:str, correct_spells:list) -> str:
    if len(word) < 3:
        return word
    if word in correct_spells:
        return word
    for good in correct_spells:
        if replace_1(word, good):
            return good
        if insert_1(word, good):
            return good
        if delete_1(word, good):
            return good

    return word

def spelling_corrector(sentence:str, correct_spells:list) -> str:
    words = sentence.strip().lower().split()
    correct_lower = [cs.lower() for cs in correct_spells]
    result = [correction(w, correct_lower) for w in words]
    return ' '.join(result)

tests = (
    ('Thes is the Firs cas', "that first case car", 'thes is the first case'),
    ('programming is fan and easy', "programming this fun easy hook", 'programming is fun and easy'),
    ('Thes is vary essy', "this is very very easy", 'this is very easy'),
    ('Wee lpve Python', "we Live In Python", 'we live python'),
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for t in tests:
        correct = t[1].split()
        print(t[0], "|", t[1], "|", t[2])
        print("Result:", spelling_corrector(t[0], correct))
        assert spelling_corrector(t[0], correct) == t[2]
```