# Python Spell Checker

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a python spell checker that accepts a string and a list. it compares each word in the string to each word in the list, and returns the result if the word in the list is one character added, subtracted, or deleted. I cannot find out how to make my variable x different each time.
Here is the code:

```
def spelling_corrector(q,r):
    def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
        s1,s2 = s1.lower(), s2.lower()
        count = 0
        if s1 == s2:
            return 0
        elif len(s1) == len(s2):
            return 2
        elif len(s1) - len(s2) == -1:
            if s1 == s2[:-1]:
                return 1
            else:
                for i in range(len(s2)):
                    if s1 == s2[:i] + s2[i+1:]:
                        return 1
                    else:
                        return 2
        elif len(s1) - len(s2) == 1:
            if s1[:-1] == s2 or s1[1:] == s2:
                return 1  

        else:
            return 2
    for word in q:
        word.lower()
        for correct in q:
            correct.lower()
            if single_insert_or_delete(word, correct) == 1:
                x = q.replace(correct)
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Isn't `q` supposed to be a sentence? (This seems to be very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672938/write-a-function-named-spelling-corrector/35673773#35673773).)

Comment: yes, q is a sentence, and split() makes it a list of words

Comment: @Auston Hastings: your answer does not seem to work!!

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues with the loop code at the bottom of your outer function.

To start with, you're looping over `q`, which I think is supposed to be a string containing any number of words. If you iterate directly on a string like this, you'll get individual characters, which I don't think you want. You probably should be using `q.split()` or something similar to break up the string into a list of word strings.

The next issue is that you're calling `word.lower()` (and later `correct.lower()`) but not doing anything with the return value. Strings in Python are immutable, so methods like `lower` return a new string with the requested changes, rather than modifying the existing string in place. You probably want `word = word.lower()` (and `correct = correct.lower()`). But this may have issues, as the changed capitalization may make the `replace` call later not work properly. A better approach may be to treat case as significant and just remove the `lower` calls.

A third issue is that your second loop is on `q` again, rather than being on `r`, which I think is supposed to be the list of correctly spelled words. (Note, you should also improve your variable names, so their meanings are obvious.) You probably want: `for correct in r:`

The final two (intertwined) issues are, I think, the ones you're actually asking about in the question. The first problem with your `replace` call in the last line is that you're only passing one argument. `str.replace` expects two (in addition to the instance it's being called on), so that won't work. Use `replace(word, correct)` to replace each occurrence of the substring `word` with `correct` (though more on why this might not be the right thing to do later).

The other issue is the variable `x`. You don't use `x` anywhere else in the code, so I don't know what you intend it to be used for. If you're just trying to make a new string with the replacements in it, I'd suggest overwriting the `q` variable with the return value of the `replace` call:

```
q = q.replace(word, correct)
```

Then just add `return q` at the bottom of the function.

Note, your function will still do the wrong thing in many cases, but fixing them will require a larger redesign. For one example of an error, if you have a string like `"an"` as `q`, and your dictionary contains `["and", "an"]` (with the longer word before the smaller one), your code will assume the `an` word string is a misspelled version of `and` and replace it. You probably need to check first if the word is correctly spelled (perhaps with `word in r`) before checking if it's one character off any other words.

Another situation it will get wrong is when a misspelled word appears as a prefix in another word (which may or may not be spelled wrong itself). Try fixing `"foo foobar"` with a word list of `["food"]` and you'll get `"food foodbar"`, since the `replace("foo", "food")` call had no respect for word boundaries.

Comment: it says that in line 26: object of type bool has no len.